# Calculating long term profit for changing expected value equations

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm working on an algorithm that predicts expected value equations of making certain moves in a probability based game. I am trying to come up with a metric that can prove that these expected value equations are accurate and the following questions I am stuck on. I have tried running these simulations comparing correct EV equations vs their one round value over a large number of rounds, but I can't come up with a metric that can quantitatively verify that the predicted EV equation is correct.

Let's say we have two vectors $p$ (probabilities) and $v$ (values) of size $n$.

Let's assume a very large amount of rounds $k$ where each round you are given a new expected value equation of EV = v · p. Is there anyway to accurately estimate net profit over $k$ rounds?

Second question. Let's say you had a way of predicting these EV equations but the only label you are given is the value of one round. Is there any metric that can be calculated that prove these predicted EV equations are accurate over a large number of rounds?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have updated my problem relating it to my application. Hopefully thats enough to get some context.